# Is it possible to detect the IP address assigned by Ngrok?

Tags: windows, networking, forwarding

I downloaded [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for windows and it works fine.

When you start ngrok (`ngrok.exe http x`) it maps localhost:x to a public IP address. eg `abcd123.ngrok.io`.

Q: Is it possible to detect what this assigned forwarding address is (specifically, the `abcd123` subdomain in my made-up example)... Or is this technically impossible? If possible, what is the command to do determine this on windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in command to achieve what you are looking for, however ngrok provides a real-time web UI where you can introspect all of the HTTP traffic running over your tunnels, where you could see all requests (including host domain). After you've started ngrok, just open http://localhost:4040 in a web browser to inspect request details.

Ngrok also provides client API listing on http://localhost:4040/api

For instance if you were to open requests on port 4000 by using a command

```
ngrok http 4000
```

It would create 2 tunnels (http and https).
If you were to make a request to http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels you would receive a JSON encoded response with the list all tunnels currently running on your machine. Looking similarly to this

```
{
  "tunnels": [
    {
      "name": "command_line",
      "uri": "/api/tunnels/command_line",
      "public_url": "https://92802df6.ngrok.io",
      "proto": "https",
      "config": {
        "addr": "http://localhost:4000",
        "inspect": true
      },
      "metrics": {
        "conns": {
          "count": 12,
          "gauge": 0,
          "rate1": 3.010161493334155e-20,
          "rate5": 0.0000023116701144869783,
          "rate15": 0.00031425303226642,
          "p50": 5006072050,
          "p90": 7160137960.000004,
          "p95": 8080786000,
          "p99": 8080786000
        },
        "http": {
          "count": 13,
          "rate1": 4.1641366552993466e-20,
          "rate5": 0.0000030815031931566885,
          "rate15": 0.00038190674419415834,
          "p50": 4962400,
          "p90": 649465039.9999996,
          "p95": 1076411200,
          "p99": 1076411200
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "command_line (http)",
      "uri": "/api/tunnels/command_line%20%28http%29",
      "public_url": "http://92802df6.ngrok.io",
      "proto": "http",
      "config": {
        "addr": "http://localhost:4000",
        "inspect": true
      },
      "metrics": {
        "conns": {
          "count": 0,
          "gauge": 0,
          "rate1": 0,
          "rate5": 0,
          "rate15": 0,
          "p50": 0,
          "p90": 0,
          "p95": 0,
          "p99": 0
        },
        "http": {
          "count": 0,
          "rate1": 0,
          "rate5": 0,
          "rate15": 0,
          "p50": 0,
          "p90": 0,
          "p95": 0,
          "p99": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "uri": "/api/tunnels"
}
```

You can find url inside of the `tunnels.[index].public_url`

You can also request http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/tunnel-name to just get details of the tunnel named `tunnel-name`